# How to find a Substring with a specific pattern?

Tags: python, string, substring

Hi guys I cannot find how to take out a substring according to a specific pattern. This string is an Android Package name

I see that there's a python library called re but I don't really understand how to use in order to replicate this pattern

cc.blynk.appexport.untrol..... -> cc.blynk.appexport

so the pattern will be 
something.something.something

Comment: Literally read the documentation.... Look at pythex or any other re tester and try things. You could have found this with minimal googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

x = 'cc.blynk.appexport.untrol'

print(re.findall(u'[^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+', x))
```

outputs:

```
['cc.blynk.appexport']
```